# How to add a label to existing colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am using a Python module called [kwant](https://kwant-project.org/) which automatically creates a complete plot for me including a colorbar. However I dont find any way to add a label to this colorbar. Since I cannot access the data that the plot is build on directly, I can only hope to be able to access the colorbar object from the already created figure object. Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: Possible solutions might also depend on what kind of label you mean. Can you either give and example or explain that (is it a ticklabel or a title?). Also it would be interesting if there is only one plot in the figure and what kind of plot that would be.

Answer (score 2):

https://kwant-project.org/doc/1/reference/generated/kwant.plotter.plot

```
colorbar : bool
Whether to show a colorbar if colormap is used. Ignored if ax is provided.
```

https://kwant-project.org/doc/1.0/reference/kwant.plotter

Have you looked this?

Comment: Yes. This goes into the direction of the comment i made under the answer by @FLab

Comment: do you have any data example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with this module but...
From the [docs](https://kwant-project.org/doc/1/reference/generated/kwant.plotter.plot#kwant.plotter.plot) the plotting function takes as input an ax from matplotlib.
So you can do something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1) 
...
out = kwant.some_plot(..., ax = ax)
```

And now you can access different parts of the plot via fig and ax, using matplotlib.

Comment: Yes i thought about this. Doing it this way however kwant does not create a colorbar. To create a color myself i need to give the data as a parameter, which I dont have. Or am i mistaken and there is a way to add a colorbar based on an existing ax rather than on the data itself?

Comment: Yes, I see...can you report what is returned by the plotting function?
so what is "out" in my sample code

Comment: the function returns a figure object if you do not pass an axes object as a parameter. If you do pass an axes object it does not return anything.